# Public enum with int values

Tags: c#, enums

I have defined a public enum like so:

```
public enum guests
{
    One,
    Two
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have it like the following

```
public enum guests
{
    1,
    2
}
```

but I keep getting this error when I try that:

```
Identifier expected
```

Can I set int instead of strings?

Comment: I think you have a conceptual misunderstanding about what enums are. They are a collection of closely related identifiers that can have a specific value. A subset of numbers is a reasonable type, but it isn't an enum (and isn't directly supported in C#).

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `int` property `GuestCount` instead of an enum?

Comment: You are so lucky, that your question was not shot into head by some super user with all the questions in the JavaScript or HTML ;). But as they were not around, luckily, you got two good answers:).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
public enum guests
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that OP can cast the enum value to `int` and use `ToString` to get the text.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply Johan's answer to:

```
public enum guests
{
     One = 1, Two
}
```

And get the same result.   In your original question you would have found One=0 and Two=1.  By specifying the value of the first element, all subsequent elements then increment by 1.

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration is a set of named integer constants. So each symbol inside the enum stands for an int, one greater than the symbol before. Defaultly, the value of the first enum symbol is 0.

```
enum Days{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun}
```

So Mon = 0, Tue = 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Identifier is a name that can be used to identify variable, method name, member name or any user defined name uniquely. Since identifier rule says that it can not be started with a digit and user defined enums contains identifier, it gives a compile time error as '`Identifier Expected`'